# how to add char buffer to std string placed in struct?

Tags: c++, std

suppose i have following struct:

```
struct A { std::string str; };
```

how can i add char buffer to std::string str placed in A struct later in program?

```
 char bufer[]="somestring";
 A* ptr=new A;
 ptr->  // how to add char buffer to std::string str here?
```

Comment: You mean, `ptr->str = buffer;` to perform the copy? Also, you probably don't need to dynamically allocate `A`.

Comment: `ptr->str = string(buffer);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char bufer[]="somestring";
A* ptr=new A;
ptr->str = buffer;
```

Also,

```
char bufer[]="somestring";
A a;
a.str = buffer;
```

Please note that `ptr` and `a` have their own copies of the string. If you change the contents of `buffer`, the values `str` in `ptr` or `a` won't change. Conversely, if you change the values `str` in `ptr` or `a`, it won't change the contents of `buffer`.